# How we impliment excplicit wait in capybara

Tags: capybara

Can anybody help , how to wait explicitly wait for a web element in capybara?
 In such a way that it will wait if it found element it will return other wise it will wait till some specified period?

Answer (score 0):

That's exactly how Capybaras `#find` works.

```
page.find(:css, '#test')
```

will wait up to Capybara.default_max_wait_time seconds for an element with id of test to appear, returning when it appears or erroring if the time expires without it appearing.  You can customize the maximum time for a single find with a :wait option

```
page.find(:css, '#slow', wait: 10) # wait up to 10 seconds for element to appear
```

Most of capybaras other methods/matchers behave the same way, other than `#all` and `#first` which won't wait unless you specify one of the count options